# What's the purpose of unique webserver names?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, nameserver

Previously I would set the name servers of a domain to what the hosting company told me (e.g. ns1.hostingcompany.com). I've now started buying domains from a company that lets you make your own nameservers (e.g. ns1.mywebsite.com) and I just enter the IP for them (I presume of my webhost server).

My question, what is the point of this? Is it purely cosmetic? (I do find this cool, that I'd have ns1.mysite.com, but I'm a geek, is there any other advantage or disadvantage to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're reselling webhosting this allows you to hide the fact that you're a reseller. It makes nosey customers feel better about their hosting choice and keeps them from going straight to the source.

Comment: There aren't any security benefits to this